Why is FireBase Authentication with Redirect Not working
The firebase signinwithpopup() works just fine but when i use signinwithredirect() it just doesnt work
the signinwithpopup() works wonderfully fine but i have to use the redirect onw for the phone and i just cant get it to work
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth, provider } from './firebaseconfig';
import { getRedirectResult,  signInWithRedirect } from "firebase/auth";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getRedirectResult(auth);
        if (result?.user) {
          setUser(result.user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting redirect result:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during sign-in:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {user ? (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome, {user.displayName}!</p>
          <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign out</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign in</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


